# list of cities name in arabic and english

Tags: sql

I am looking for a list of cities by country (the countries I mean here are all countries that exist on planet Earth) i want to show the English and Arabic names of the country and s
city. Is there any open-source SQL database available online which I can download and use, Excel file I Can use?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at http://www.geonames.org/export/ or http://www.geodatasource.com.

Answer (score 1):

The World Gazetteer provides a downloadable file that contains a list
of all cities, towns, administrative divisions and agglomerations with
their current population, their English name parent country.

World Gazetteer

http://www.world-gazetteer.com/wg.php?x=1129163518&men=stdl&lng=en&gln=xx&dat=32&srt=npan&col=aohdq

Download the file here:  (3 MB)

http://www.world-gazetteer.com/dataen.zip

Additional information
- Structure of the file
- Importing the file to Excel

http://www.world-gazetteer.com/wg.php?x=1129163518&men=stdl&lng=en&gln=xx&dat=32&srt=npan&col=aohdq

==================================

Another option would be the Geobytes database.

GeoWorldMap is a database that contains the cities of the world with
their country, region, latitude, longitude and more.

http://www.geobytes.com/FreeServices.htm

Download here:

http://www.geobytes.com/GeoWorldMap.zip

===================================

For the Arabic names, try to connect to google translate API and send the database one by one to translate them, I think it should work nicely.

I cannot find a similarly accurate database in Arabic...